# What techniques to usually think about when facing "show this is a diffeomorphism"?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $g\colon\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function, with $g(t)>0$ for all $t\geq 0$.

Let $U=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^{2}:0<x<y\}$ and define a function $f\colon U\to\mathbb{R}^{2}$ putting
\begin{equation}
f(x,y)=\Big(\int_{0}^{x+y}g(t)\,dt, \int_{0}^{y-x}g(t)\,dt\Big).
\end{equation}
Show that $f$ is a diffeomorphism over an open set of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$.

Hey guys, I'm stuck in this real analysis exercise. I have little idea how to start because I don't know if there is a general sort of 'method' for proving something is a diffeomorphism. I've seen other similar questions here on MSE and I found that the techniques are very diverse, based on the hypothesis of the exercise. When there is some hypothesis on boundness of derivative of the function, we can try to use Banach fixed point theorem, for instance. In this case, I really don't see what to use. I always try to explain my attempts on my questions here but this one unfortunately I can't even start. Can you guys give me some tips for this one?

Also, what are some good 'techniques' to keep in mind facing a "show this is a diffeomorphism" exercise?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: The first technique that should spring to mind for _every_ "show that this-and-that is a such-and-such" exercise is to find the definition of such-and-such and go through the conditions, checking whether it is easy to prove each of them from the definitions one by one. Only if that does _not_ succeed should you begin looking for more specific "techniques". (And if you do reach that point before you ask the question, you need to explain _which of the properties in the definition_ where the straightforward approach doesn't work for you).

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! Yeah, so, I think in these diffeomorphism problems surjectivity is usually the issue (not all the time, of course). I get what you're saying, but analysis exercises, at least for me, usually involves various "tricks" and is (almost) never really stragihtforward, say, as an algebra exercise.

Comment: I think that the problem you describe is very straightforward, and no "tricks" are needed at all (the only trick I can conceive is to define $G(\xi):=\int\limits_0^\xi g(t)\,dt$ and observe that $f(x,y)=(G(x+y),G(y-x))$). Do you see that $f$ is one-to-one?

Comment: Yep. I think the surjectivity problem I mention is like how to show $f(U)$ is open. I can't see exactly what $f(U)$ looks like.

Comment: You can notice that $f$ is a composition of two diffeomorpshisms: First $(x,y)\mapsto(\xi,\eta)$, where $\xi=x+y$, $\eta=y-x$. The image of $U$ equals, if my calculations are correct, $V=\{(\xi,\eta)|\xi>0,\ 0<\eta<\xi\}$. The image of $V$ under $(\xi,\eta)\mapsto(\alpha,\beta)$, where $\alpha=G(\xi)$, $\beta=G(\eta)$, equals $\{(\alpha,\beta)|0<\alpha<G(\infty),\ 0<\beta<\alpha\}$, where $G(\infty)=\int\limits_0^\infty g(t)\,dt$.

Comment: A friend suggested first showing that $f$ is injective and hence bijective over the image $f(U)$. Then, by inverse function theorem we have local differentiable inverses with coincide with this 'global inverse' restricted locally, and hence this global inverse is differentiable in every point. So it is a diffeomorphism and $f(U)$ is open. Looks correct, right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.